# if pattern is matched then shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

I have file that contains below words

```
gl-events_0
gl-events_1
gl-events_2
gl-mx-events_0
gl-mx-events_1
gl-mx-events_2
```

so i want if match pattern in gl-events it should run command A if patter is gl-mx-events it should run command B

i tried with below but its not working for me

```
STR='gl-mx-events_0'
SUB='gl-mx-events'
if [[ "$STR" == *"$SUB"* ]]; then
echo "you need to run command B"
```

my requirement is if patter is matching according to word it should run

```
command A --- (only for gl-events_0 ...... gl-events_10)
command B --- (only for gl-mx-events_0 ...... gl-mx-events_10)
```

can someone please guide me how I can achieve this.

Regards,
SAMURAI

Comment: Complicated approach. I assume you want to pass your match to a command? If yes, you could use `grep` to seperate your patterns, and pipe that output to `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
n=1
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = *gl-events* ]]; then
        printf "line %d has gl_events, doing something\n"  "$n"
        # run command A with "$line"
    fi
    if [[ $line = *gl-mx-events* ]]; then
        printf "line %d has gl-mx-events, doing something different\n"  "$n"
        # run command B with "$line"
    fi
    n=$((n+1))
done  < file
```

But like @Panki's comment says, you could also use `grep` to filter the lines based on the keyword, and then have `xargs` execute the required command. E.g. with the GNU version of xargs:

```
< file grep ^gl-events_    |xargs -d '\n' -n1 echo "running command A with arg" 
< file grep ^gl-mx-events_ |xargs -d '\n' -n1 echo "running command B with arg"
```

(By default `xargs` treats *any* whitespace in the input as separating the input elements, and interprets quotes and backslashes in a way that's incompatible with anything. The `-d '\n'` tells it to use the input lines as-is instead.)